# java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException на Windows 10

Tags: java, windows-10

При перемещении каталога c Files.move(Path sourse, Path target) получаю java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException в Windows 10. В Windows 7 все работает. Каталог содержит файлы. У всего дерева снят атрибут только для чтения, текущий пользователь доступ к изменению имеет, целевая директория не существует и не открыта в проводнике.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всему виной незакрытый InputSreamReader на один из файлов внутри каталога.